# Imagebutton with sound is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, imagebutton

i made a program in android studio which has 10 imagebutton, each imagebutton when clicked will produce a sound. However, when i run them on emulator only first 7 imagebutton will produce a sound (don't care what order the button i clicked on). Im new to this, help me, This is my code:

```
public class playtimang extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playtimang);

    final MediaPlayer satukecik = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one_kecik);
    final MediaPlayer satubesar = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.one_besar);
    final MediaPlayer duakecik = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two_kecik);
    final MediaPlayer duabesar = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.two_besar);
    final MediaPlayer tigakecik = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three_kecik);
    final MediaPlayer tigabesar = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.three_besar);
    final MediaPlayer limakecik = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.five_kecik);
    final MediaPlayer limabesar = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.five_besar);
    final MediaPlayer enamkecik = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.six_kecik);
    final MediaPlayer enambesar = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.six_besar);

    ImageButton satu_kecikIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.satukecikIB);
    ImageButton satu_besarIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.satubesarIB);
    ImageButton dua_kecikIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.duakecikIB);
    ImageButton dua_besarIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.duabesarIB);
    ImageButton tiga_kecikIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.tigakecikIB);
    ImageButton tiga_besarIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.tigabesarIB);
    ImageButton lima_kecikIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.limakecikIB);
    ImageButton lima_besarIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.limabesarIB);
    ImageButton enam_kecikIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.enamkecikIB);
    ImageButton enam_besarIB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.enambesarIB);

    satu_kecikIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            satukecik.start();
        }
    });

    satu_besarIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            satubesar.start();
        }
    });

    dua_kecikIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            duakecik.start();
        }
    });

    dua_besarIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            duabesar.start();
        }
    });

    tiga_kecikIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tigakecik.start();
        }
    });

    tiga_besarIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tigabesar.start();
        }
    });

    lima_kecikIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            limakecik.start();
        }
    });

    lima_besarIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            limabesar.start();
        }
    });

    enam_kecikIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enamkecik.start();
        }
    });

    enam_besarIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enambesar.start();
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Use Log to test if the OnClickListeners are being called, and test if calling the MediaPlayers from other places(like in onCreate) works for the not working MediaPlayers

Comment: is your problem is not playing audio for last three buttons

Comment: check once audio files which are starting in not playing image buttons

Comment: Brother don't use Media player's methods for tones or alerts try to use `SoundPool` class which is designed specially such purposes. Here is the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `MediaPlayer` is made for some long running or big media files which includes various formats of Videos, audios so making use of it for some small tones is bad because it itself includes big calculations to perform. There is a [architecture diagram](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to follow to make use of `MediaPlayer` well instead you should use `SoundPool` because it is designed for such purposes only.

Now the main answer to your problem is

As stated on official documentation

> "Create" Added in API level 1
>
> MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid)
>
> Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result in an exception. Note that since prepare() is called automatically in this method, you cannot change the audio stream type (see setAudioStreamType(int)), audio session ID (see setAudioSessionId(int)) or audio attributes (see setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes) of the new MediaPlayer.

In short you must follow the state diagram of `MediaPlayer` to get safety from such kind of errors or exceptions. You must call release method to release the resources after every call.