# Mediaplayer. The song from URL unable to play when go second activity.

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i plan to create an app to allows user to streaming song from URL, SO, i have 1 button in main_activity that link to second activity. In second activity, i have 2 button which play from URL and Stop from URL. Then Play/Stop is work fine when it is on main activity, but it wont work when it is on second activity.

This is MainActivity:

```js
package example.cjie.com.streamingdropboxmusicdemo3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


    public void Song2Activity(View view){
        Intent Song2Intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(Song2Intent);
    }

}
```

This is Main2Activity:

```js
package example.cjie.com.streamingdropboxmusicdemo3;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private Button buttonStop,buttonStart;

    MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        buttonStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttonStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {

                    mediaplayer.setDataSource(getResources().getString(R.string.song1));
                    mediaplayer.prepareAsync();


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaplayer.start();
                return;

            }
        });

        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mediaplayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaplayer.reset();
                    //mediaplayer.release();
                    //return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is error message:

```js
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

          [ 10-05 01:07:59.684 18774:18798 E/         ]
          Device driver API match
          Device driver API version: 29
          User space API version: 29 


          [ 10-05 01:07:59.684 18774:18798 E/         ]
          mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul 22 19:59:34 KST 2014 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x519e2b10 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x519e7fa8
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.nativeSetDataSource(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1080)
W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1041)
W/System.err:     at example.cjie.com.streamingdropboxmusicdemo3.Main2Activity$1.onClick(Main2Activity.java:38)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/MediaPlayer: start called in state 1
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

Appreciate Some help and advices . Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should implement your media player on a Service instead of calling it from the activity. By doind this, depending on how you start the service, the process you keep running even if the component that started it is destroyed

Comment: Thanks! you give me a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Well we have to consider some important things right now.

Firstly I want to make you to know why to use and how to use services in android. You would be amazed when you will come to know how fantastic it is.

Playing Media from Service is the finest way to play media on device. So firstly you have to consider using services to play media on device.

However If you still want to play media from Activity then, the main cause you are not able to get it is, you are not implementing MediaPlayer lifecycle in well manner. Follow my answer on another question where cause of problem was the same. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308890/imagebutton-with-sound-is-not-working/39309699#39309699). You have to implement lifecycle of MediaPlayer class perfectly otherwise it would produce exception or even crashes.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks! you give me a great idea!

Comment: If you feel my answer solved your problem then you can accept the answer it would feel me good to answer more. Or if you feel my answer helped you elsewhere then you can up vote it. It would be really helpful for me. Thank and best of luck.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar hi i got only this error : JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0 i tried all the possible solution i cant find any solution can you help me? i'm fetching audio file from whatsapp folder and setDataSource.

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi I think you might have passed wrong context to media player or either your media volume is zero.

Comment: @DushyantSuthar yes media volume was zero I set it again its working now but can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425632/android-mediaplayer-play-pause-resume-audio-file-like-whatsapp