# In an Android fragment no sound is played after an onClick event

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am new to all this so I started to write this app to learn.

The app starts with 6 clickable images that lead to a secondary activity composed of a series of "swipeable" screens each with an image that when clicked upon will generate a sound. Here is the code of the secondary and fragment code necessary to generated the screens :

SecondaryPage.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SecondaryPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.secondary);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

SimpleFragmentAdapter.java

AnimalsFragement.java (`Croc()` and `Camel()` are identical, except for the name)

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.testfrags.R.layout.animals;

public class AnimalsFragment extends Fragment {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = null;
        //Inflating View to access it's resources

        v = inflater.inflate(animals, container, false);
        Log.i("AnimalsFragment", "mp before playing: " + mp);

        //creating clickable image

        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.jungle_animals);

        // Sound played once clicked
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start playback.
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.lioncub2);
                Log.i("AnimalsFragment", "mp: " + mp);
                mp.start();
                mp.stop();//Stops playback - added precaution

                // release media resources
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                Log.i("AnimalsFragment", "mp after release: " + mp);
                // Little msg confirm end of sound
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Questo era il Leoncino", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return v;
    } // end of onCreatView

    /**
     * Clean up the media player by releasing its resources.
     */
    private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
        // If the media player is not null, then it may be currently playing a sound.
        if (mp != null) {
            // Regardless of the current state of the media player, release its resources
            // because we no longer need it.
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();

            // Set the media player back to null. 

        } // end of if
    } // end of releaseMediaPlayer

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();  // Always call the superclass method first
        releaseMediaPlayer();

    }


}
```

These are the xml files :
secondary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/viewpager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

animals.xml (croc.xml and camel.xml are the same)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/jungle_animals"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/lion"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The app compiles and runs but when I click on any image in any fragment no sound is played. I have tried both on my device and emulated but nothing.

What have I done wrong ?

I have tried changing `getActivity()` with `v.getContext()` in the line :

```
`mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.lioncub2);`
```

but nothing changes.
All sound files are mp3. I have also written a version of secondaryPage.java without the fragments with the three images just to see if the mp3 files would work and they all played normally.
I also inserted the `Toast` message just to check if the `onClick()` method was working, which it does.
When I debug and step into the `mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.lioncub2);` line and continue, the sound is played.

Here is the output of the Log.i statements :

```
10-15 10:50:36.962 2459-2459/com.example.testfrags I/Croc: mp before playing: null
10-15 10:50:37.682 2459-2459/com.example.testfrags I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-15 10:50:39.472 2459-2459/com.example.testfrags I/AnimalsFragment: mp: android.media.MediaPlayer@b0fd1480
10-15 10:50:39.482 2459-2459/com.example.testfrags I/AnimalsFragment: mp after release: null
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth.... 
the fault in the code was in calling the `releaseMediaPlayer` method before the sound actually finished. 
So I should have have checked this by adding some form of control, which I did using  `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`.

I did this by defining a variable and invoking `MediaPalyer.OnCompletionListner` :

```
 private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        releaseMediaPlayer();
    }
```

and then by calling the following just after the sound starts playing :

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
```

Thanks to all !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are stopping and releasing the mediaplayer just after when it is started. Remove the stop method from your code and sound will be played.

And now just removing stop will not solve your whole problem you have to do some work now if you want to use `MediaPlayer` class because `MediaPlayer` requires a lot of work around

If your sound or audio is small in duration you should use `SoundPool` class .

Your problem seems similar to this question which i have answered earlier.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39308890/imagebutton-with-sound-is-not-working/39309699#39309699)

**To Solve your problem:**

**Solution 1:**

Declare `mediaPlayer` in Activity class holding the fragments and implement `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener`

```
... MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{...
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    ....
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) 
{
int position= tab.getPosition();
switch(position)
  {
  case 1: if(mediaPlayer!=null)
            {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.realse();
            }
  break;
  case 2: if(mediaPlayer!=null)
            {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.realse();
            }
  break;
  ....
  }
....
}
```

Now in your Fragment just add MainActivity's reference like this:

```
public class AnimalsFragment extends Fragment {
private ImageView imageView;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
    ....
    ....
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Start playback.
           mainActivity.mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(mainActivity, R.raw.song);
           mediaPlayer.start();

           ....
           ....
         ....}
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the stop method but nothing changed. MediaPlayer previously (no fragment coding) had no problem in reproducing the file, so I can't see why it is not working now.

Comment: I will give you answer first tell me what type of audio you want to play are they short or long?

Comment: That's very kind of you. The audio files are animal sounds in mp3 files, so not too long.

Comment: So in that scene you should not use Media Player class instead you should use SoundPool class it is build for such kind of files. Well reason for not to use Media Player class is given in the link I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: If you still want to use media player then I am going to edit the answer wait for some time.

Comment: Before that I would like you to test the code without calling release and stop

Comment: HI, sorry for the late reply. Thank you very very much for your help. I tried not calling both the release and stop methods but that also did not change anything. It slips my grip why it won't work. I will try out the code you suggest and I will let you know. I must first try to understand it (including research). Thanks again.